# How to Delete Horizontal Lines in Microsoft Word That Won't Go Away

Tags: ms-word

The Word file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/uzax8ybhhc86v5vi3qju6/.docx?rlkey=omwdv2lgib1rp3yjyuy9mbdz4&dl=0

Where did it come from and how to remove it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. *(This is a horizontal line (shape) in the First-Page header.)*